# Select n:n relationship in one row with Oracle (to create an view)

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have some trouble to create an View in Oracle which does some joins. Main Problem: Get an n:n relationship represented in on result Row?
Oracle 10.x

**Table: HAS_APPLICATIONS**

```
USER_ID  APPLICATION_ID
-------  --------------
1        1
1        2
4        2
4        1
2        1
2        3
```

**Table: APPLICATIONS**

```
ID             APPLICATION
---------      -----------
1              Windows
2              OSx
3              FreeDos
```

**Table: USERS**

```
USER_ID        NAME
-------        ---------
1              Bob
4              Johny
2              Elvis
```

I need an View (select) like:

```
USER_ID NAME   APPLICATIONS
1       Bob    Windows, OSx
2       Elvis  Windows, FreeDos
4       Johny  OSx, Freedos
```

My "not working" Query:

```
SELECT
  u.NAME,
    (SELECT
       APPLICATION_ID
    FROM
        HAS_APPLICATIONS        
    LEFT JOIN APPLICATIONS ON HAS_APPLICATIONS.USER_ID = APPLICATIONS.ID
    WHERE
        HAS_APPLICATIONS.USER_ID = u.ID) ???????????
FROM
   USERS u
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below query. Don't know whether it works in 10G, but it works fine in 11G.

```
SELECT
  u.NAME,    
  (SELECT
     (RTRIM(XMLAGG(xmlelement(X, APPLICATIONS.APPLICATION||',')order by APPLICATIONS.APPLICATION).extract('//text()'),','))  
    FROM
        HAS_APPLICATIONS        
    LEFT JOIN APPLICATIONS ON HAS_APPLICATIONS.USER_ID = APPLICATIONS.ID
    WHERE
        HAS_APPLICATIONS.USER_ID = u.ID)          
FROM
   USERS u
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php). In Oracle 11gR2 it's easy, in previous version it's a little bit more complicated but can be done.